# Core plot objective-c, I am using CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic, my minorTickLabels are over writing the majorTickLabel values

Tags: core-plot

Core plot objective-c, I am using CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic. my minorTickLabels are over writing the majorTickLabel values. How to stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug in Core Plot. Please report it on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).